# Can one partially apply the second argument of a function that takes no keyword arguments?

Tags: python, arguments, partial-application

Take for example the python built in `pow()` function.

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

from functools import partial

list(map(partial(pow,2),xs))

>>> [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 128, 256]
```

but how would I raise the xs to the power of 2?

to get `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 49, 64]`

```
list(map(partial(pow,y=2),xs))

TypeError: pow() takes no keyword arguments
```

I know list comprehensions would be easier.

Comment: another usage of partial starting from 2-nd argument is partial for method(s) omitting self argument

Comment: for methods you can use: `def meth(cls, self,...)` and then `partial(meth, cls)`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## No

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial.args), [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) *cannot* do this (emphasis my own):

> **partial.args**
>
> > The *leftmost* positional arguments that will be prepended to the positional arguments

---

You could always just "fix" `pow` to have keyword args:

```
_pow = pow
pow = lambda x, y: _pow(x, y)
```

Comment: if in python 4.X pow() is "fixed", we will all know where they got their idea from :)

Comment: @beoliver: Actually, as of [PEP-457](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/), positional-only arguments are formalized into what seems to be a feature, so I would never expect a fix to `pow`

Comment: When using lambda here, you don't need the `functools.partial()` anymore.

Comment: What is this doing?  The arguments have not been changed at all: i would have anticipated a reversal of the order of x,y -> y,x

Comment: Following up on my comment: should not one or other of `lambda x,y` and  `_pow(x,y)` have the `x,y` reversed??

Comment: @javadba: No, the context of that line is to _'"fix" `pow` to have keyword args"_. Once you've done that, the question is no longer relevant, as `pow` is no longer _"a function that takes no keyword arguments"_. The OPs code that fails above works if preceded with this "fix".

Comment: honestly partial could've been perfect if they just let you submit a tuple of tuples of the form (arg_index, value). Why didn't they just include that to kill the problem once and for all

Answer (score 22):

Why not just create a quick lambda function which reorders the args and partial that

```
partial(lambda p, x: pow(x, p), 2)
```

Comment: I just found that method useful when defining a property (using property() function directly, rather than as a decorator), where I needed to default the second argument to a __setitem__() call.

Comment: At that point, why partial it?  Why not f = lambda p, x=2: pow(x, p).  Or even f = lambda p: pow(2, p)

Answer (score 20):

I think I'd just use this simple one-liner:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.imap(pow, [1, 2, 3], itertools.repeat(2)))
```

**Update:**

I also came up with a funnier than useful solution. It's a beautiful syntactic sugar, profiting from the fact that the `...` literal means `Ellipsis` in Python3. It's a modified version of `partial`, allowing to omit some positional arguments between the leftmost and rightmost ones. The only drawback is that you can't pass anymore Ellipsis as argument.

```
import itertools
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(newfunc.leftmost_args + fargs + newfunc.rightmost_args), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    args = iter(args)
    newfunc.leftmost_args = tuple(itertools.takewhile(lambda v: v != Ellipsis, args))
    newfunc.rightmost_args = tuple(args)
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc

>>> print partial(pow, ..., 2, 3)(5) # (5^2)%3
1
>>> print partial(pow, 2, ..., 3)(5) # (2^5)%3
2
>>> print partial(pow, 2, 3, ...)(5) # (2^3)%5
3
>>> print partial(pow, 2, 3)(5) # (2^3)%5
3
```

So the the solution for the original question would be with this version of partial `list(map(partial(pow, ..., 2),xs))`

Comment: nice, for some reason I never use repeat.  and as I'm on 3.X, it's just `list(map(pow, [1, 2, 3], itertools.repeat(2)))`

Comment: nice, I didn't know they changed `map` in Python3

Comment: The funny one is pretty clever in a somewhat horrifying way :P (Also, you're not really supposed to pass Ellipsis around to begin with, so that's not much of a disadvantage. Unless you count "using Ellipsis for something it's not meant to be used" a disadvantage.)

Comment: after learning some functional programming, for me it looks like a bizarre way of function currying in python

Comment: @kosii That's exactly what it is.  It's impressive that Python is flexible enough to facilitate many of these functional patterns.

Answer (score 8):

You could create a helper function for this:

```
from functools import wraps
def foo(a, b, c, d, e):
    print('foo(a={}, b={}, c={}, d={}, e={})'.format(a, b, c, d, e))

def partial_at(func, index, value):
    @wraps(func)
    def result(*rest, **kwargs):
        args = []
        args.extend(rest[:index])
        args.append(value)
        args.extend(rest[index:])
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar = partial_at(foo, 2, 'C')
    bar('A', 'B', 'D', 'E') 
    # Prints: foo(a=A, b=B, c=C, d=D, e=E)
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this with keyword arguments so it might blow up because of them somehow. Also I'm not sure if this is what `@wraps` should be used for but it seemed right -ish.

Comment: Major +1. I was tempted to select this answer, but I suppose I was thinking more about the inbuilt `functools.partial`. But this is definitely being saved. I like :)

Answer (score 6):

you could use a closure

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def closure(method, param):
  def t(x):
    return method(x, param)
  return t

f = closure(pow, 2)
f(10)
f = closure(pow, 3)
f(10)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `lambda`, which is more flexible than `functools.partial()`:

```
pow_two = lambda base: pow(base, 2)
print(pow_two(3))  # 9
```

More generally:

```
def bind_skip_first(func, *args, **kwargs):
  return lambda first: func(first, *args, **kwargs)

pow_two = bind_skip_first(pow, 2)
print(pow_two(3))  # 9
```

One down-side of lambda is that some libraries are not able to serialize it.

Comment: What do you mean with some libraries? I think no library is able to serialize them.

Comment: I'm often using ruamel.yaml and it serializes lambdas fine.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking about the built-in modules. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be:

```
def testfunc1(xs):
    from functools import partial
    def mypow(x,y): return x ** y
    return list(map(partial(mypow,y=2),xs))
```

but this involves re-defining the pow function.

if the use of partial was not 'needed' then a simple lambda would do the trick

```
def testfunc2(xs):
    return list(map(lambda x: pow(x,2), xs))
```

And a specific way to map the pow of 2 would be

```
def testfunc5(xs):
    from operator import mul
    return list(map(mul,xs,xs))
```

but none of these fully address the problem directly of partial applicaton in relation to keyword arguments

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question was already answered, you can get the results you're looking for with a recipe taken from [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```py
from itertools import repeat


xs = list(range(1, 9))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
xs_pow_2 = list(map(pow, xs, repeat(2)))  # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: beautiful :). Just did something similar on our side with dict:

`def _remove_table_id(ds: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    return list(map(dict.pop, ds, repeat('table_id')))`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it, provided the function takes keyword arguments. You just need to know the name.

In the case of `pow()` (provided you are using Python 3.8 or newer) you need `exp` instead of y.

Try to do:

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(list(map(partial(pow,exp=2),xs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said that's a limitation of [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) if the function you want to `partial` doesn't accept keyword arguments.

If you don't mind using an external library <sup>1</sup> you could use [`iteration_utilities.partial`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/partial.html) which has a partial that supports placeholders:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import partial
>>> square = partial(pow, partial._, 2)  # the partial._ attribute represents a placeholder
>>> list(map(square, xs))
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [`iteration_utilities`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities) library (installation instructions can be found [in the documentation](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) in case you're interested).

Answer (score 1):

The very versatile [funcy](http://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) includes an `rpartial` function that exactly addresses this problem.

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
from funcy import rpartial
list(map(rpartial(pow, 2), xs))
# [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

It's just a lambda under the hood:

```
def rpartial(func, *args):
    """Partially applies last arguments."""
    return lambda *a: func(*(a + args))
```

Comment: Not "exactly". The second argument need not necessarily be the last one.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use lambda functions, you can also write a simple wrapper function that reorders the arguments.

```
def _pow(y, x):
    return pow(x, y)
```

and then call

```
list(map(partial(_pow,2),xs))

>>> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Yes**

**if you created your partial class**

```
class MyPartial:
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        self._func = func
        self._args = args
        
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self._func(*args, *self._args) # swap ordering
    
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list(map(MyPartial(pow,2),xs))

>>> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```