# How to curry a function at a given argument position

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying

Is it possible to curry a function at a user-defined n-th position? Functool's partial function can handle partial evaluation of multiple arguments that

```
from functools import partial

def f(x,y,z):
    return [x,y,z]
```

Then

```
partial(f,1)(2,3)
```

> [1,2,3]

and

```
partial(f,1,2)(3)
```

> [1,2,3]

Is it possibly to curry at a given argument position?

```
curry_at(f,n)
```

So that

```
curry_at(f,2)(1,3)(2)
```

gives

> [1,2,3]

where, I think to keep consistent with possible *arg and **kwarg, `n` should be no larger than the number of regular arguments?

Is there a method to enumerate the arguments to separate the prefix and postfix arguments to the n-th slot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one partially apply the second argument of a function that takes no keyword arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173660/can-one-partially-apply-the-second-argument-of-a-function-that-takes-no-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

It's not common to recommend building functions like this, but in this case, I think it's better to have to have static definitions with a little bit of duplication rather than relying on a dynamic function whose complex behavior is difficult to verify -

```
def apply_at_1 (f, *a, **kw):
  return lambda x, *a2, **kw2: \
    f(x, *a, *a2, **kw, **kw2)

def apply_at_2 (f, *a, **kw):
  return lambda x, y, *a2, **kw2: \
    f(x, y, *a, *a2, **kw, **kw2)

def apply_at_3 (f, *a, **kw):
  return lambda x, y, z, *a2, **kw2: \
    f(x, y, z, *a, *a2, **kw, **kw2)

def dummy (a, b, c, d, *more):
  print (a, b, c, d, *more)

apply_at_1(dummy, 2, 3, 4)(1, 5, 6, 7, 8)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

apply_at_2(dummy, 3, 4, 5)(1, 2, 6, 7, 8)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

apply_at_3(dummy, 4, 5, 6)(1, 2, 3, 7, 8)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Sure, the dynamic function allows you to apply an argument in *any* position, but if you need to apply an argument at position four (the 5th argument), maybe it's time to consider a refactor. In this case I think it's better to set a sensible limit and then discipline yourself.

Other functional languages do similar things for typing reasons. Consider Haskell's `liftA2`, `liftA3`, `liftA4`, etc. Or Elm's `List.map`, `List.map2`, `List.map3`, `List.map4`, ...

Sometimes it's just easier to KISS.

---

Here's a version of `partial` supporting wild-cards, `__` -

```
def __ ():
  return None;

def partial (f, *a):
  def combine (a, b):
    if not a:
      return b
    elif a[0] is __:
      return (b[0], *combine(a[1:], b[1:]))
    else:
      return (a[0], *combine(a[1:], b))
  return lambda *b: f(*combine(a,b))

def dummy (a, b, c, d, *more):
  print (a, b, c, d, *more)

partial(dummy, 1, __, __, 4)(2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8) 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

partial(dummy, __, __, 3, __, __, 6, 7, 8)(1, 2, 4, 5)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: I use the "dynamic" version all the time in another functional, optionally typed language (which moreover allows a direct positional wildcard operator at the desired position to indicate it). I can't think of a reason why you would think this is better.

Comment: PS, as long as the KISS is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @alancalvitti because there's zero complexity and virtually nothing to test. It's basically a syntax rewriter. Any dynamic implementation will be slower as more intermediate values and error-prone logic is required. I called out the "duplication" in my post, and already said it's not common to write functions this way. However in this specific scenario, I think this approach has many advantages. And by evidence of other popular languages using similar techniques, I think it adds credibility to the answer. If/when you find/write a dynamic solution to use in Python, please share it.

Comment: I don't know what can be done in Python, it's a far less powerful language than what I've been using for 20+ years (see Paul Graham's [Blub paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Graham_(programmer)#The_Blub_paradox) ). But I can tell you the dynamic version I use on a daily basis and there are no problems or material slow-downs - as you point out it's handled by the interpreter as a simple term rewrite.

Comment: _”the dynamic version I use on a daily basis...”_ - in what lang? Lisp? That’s hardly a fair comparison. You’re asking how to do this in Python and the language capabilities are completely different.

Comment: I've been using Mathematica (Wolfram Language) where the curry function lets you even permute the order of arguments. With that, I made what I'd really like to replicate in Py, which is a positional curry syntax like `f(1,2,*,4)` where the wildcard indicates which position to partial - to streamline functional data pipes.

Comment: @alancalvitti per your comment, I added an implementation of `partial` that supports wild-card arguments

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for this syntax: `dummy(1, __, __, 4)` - the wildcard(s) are then interpreted to partial the function (note `partial` is not directly invoked by  user).

Answer (score 0):

I tryed  a workarond using the index and a for loop, hope it helps:

```
from functools import partial

def curry_at(funtion,parameter,index,*args):
  h = funtion
  index-=1
  ls = list(args)
  ls.insert(index,parameter)
  for arg in ls:
      h = partial(h,arg)
  return h()

a = curry_at(f,'a',2,'c','d')

b = curry_at(f,2,2,1,3)
```

> a
>
> ['c', 'a', 'd']
>
> b
>
> [1,2,3]

Comment: @alancalvitti that because you missunderstood the signature, first the index then the param, I will make the adjustments. look

Comment: @alancalvitti I made an update in the answer, could you try it now?

Comment: Couple of issues - probably fixable. First, `curry_at` should return a function so that parameter can be applied to this function. Also eg `curry_at(f,'x',5,'a','c','d')` incorrectly inserts 'x' at the wrong position. Perhaps more difficult, how to handle `**kwarg`?

Comment: 1) to simply return a function, you return `h` instead of `h()`, and of course that curry_at(f,'x', 5, 'a','b', 'c') will act extrange, you must know the amount of parameters of the function before use this particular curry_at

Comment: you would not pass the parameter 'x' when calling `curry_at`. That would be passed to the function returned by `curry_at`